# RequestMethod.DELETE not working

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a DELETE request using FireFox RestClient

Details below:

**Method** : DELETE

**URL** :

```
http://hostname:port/my-web/test/batch
```

**Headers** : Content-Type: application/json

**BODY**:

```
{
    "users": [
    "string1",
    "string2"
    ]
}
```

MY JAVA CONTROLLER is

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.DELETE}, value = "/batch")
public MYHTTPEntity<RestResponse> bulkDelete(@RequestBody String[] users,    WebRequest request){
..
}
```

I am getting 400 Bad Request. Description :The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Please help check what is wrong. All my other requests are working fine with similar setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `MYHTTPEntity<RestResponse>` is something you have setup that is valid to be returned by the controller, based on the JSON you are sending you need to do the following:

Add a class that will map the request, for example `DeleteContent`

```
public class DeleteContent {
    private List<String> users;

    public List<String> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<String> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Then the controller would be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.DELETE}, value = "/batch")
public MYHTTPEntity<RestResponse> bulkDelete(@RequestBody DeleteContent deleteContent, WebRequest request){
..
}
```

If `MYHTTPEntity<RestResponse>` is not valid, you could return some custom object using

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.DELETE}, value = "/batch")
public @ResponseBody YourCustomResponse bulkDelete(@RequestBody DeleteContent deleteContent, WebRequest request){
..
}
```

Comment: Does it mean @RequestBody does not accept array as parameter ?

Comment: The json you are sending does correspond to String[]

Comment: Hi geoand. That's true. I did not understand why can't I use RequestBody String[] users ? Why do i need to create a object DeleteContent and use RequestBody DeleteContent deleteContent instead?

Comment: If you were to send ["user1", "user2"] as your JSON then you could just use `List<String> users` (I am not sure about `String[] users` since I have never used it before). But the way your JSON is structured does not correspond to an array